# GWT and JSNI. Check if function is defined

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

There is a JavaScript function in html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function someFunction(){
    return "<b>some text</b>";
}
```

And JSNI:

```
native String someFunction() /*-{
    return $wnd.someFunction();
}-*/;
```

The problem is that the first script is not allways defined. How can it be checked if function is defined?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with JSNI - but in JS you can do:

```
if ( typeof someFunction == 'function' ) { ... }
```

Comment: for correctness sake, you better check `if ( typeof someFunction !== 'undefined' )`.

Answer (score 2):

you can relay on the returned boolean value of a `defined` check, and do this:

```
native String someFunction() /*-{
    if ($wnd.someFunction) {
        return $wnd.someFunction();
    }
    return '';
}-*/;
```